# Navigate to folder with Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, http, google-api, http-headers, google-drive-api

I need to know how to correctly use the File Search method parameters, in order to walk folder trees in the Drive API.

Using Javascript, I've gone through the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js), set up the app and the API enabling in the Google Dev Console, am authorized, and can read file names at root with the `gapi.client.drive.files.list()` method, but am stuck at the point of running the [Files Search](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) call in order to navigate to a particular directory.

I'm trying variants of this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='0B36wII03Fph8aFhtTFN5SVRYR0U'+in+parents&key={CLIENT_ID}
```

... but I'm confused as to how to call the GET request. I've never used REST calls straight from JS/HTML before, so I could just be missing something basic... but yeah, I don't really know how to use that in my code...

I've tried to play with the query parameters on the [Files:List](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) page, with just the fileID as a parameter, but I keep getting a 400 response:

```
400 OK
- SHOW HEADERS -
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but the pure Http Rest stuff isn't my forte... Thanks for any leads!

Comment: to start with Key is not client id its an api key and will only work for public requests not requests like this which will require authentication for that you need to use access_token={access_token}  However this is not your question but it will be once you fix the q parm

Comment: Just to elaborate what @DalmTo said the key is not the client_id. It is the API key which you can get in the Developer Console.

Comment: Oh, am I using the wrong key? Okay, will test that ASAP! :/

Comment: Okay, looking at the Files:List parameters again, I understand the syntax and am able to get a 200 response search for a Folder by Name. Thanks! But I can't seem to figure out the query by fileID.. which is fine I guess, cause the name does the same thing. But i'd prefer to have the ID, as it stays the same while the Name of the folder/fil can be changed..

Comment: @DaImTo I am in an authenticated context by the time I am calling this, btw

Answer (score 2):

Try different encoding for your `q` parameter.

Instead of

```
q='0B36wII03Fph8aFhtTFN5SVRYR0U'+in+parents
```

use this:

```
q=%270B36wII03Fph8aFhtTFN5SVRYR0U%27%20in%20parents
```

Oh, and update to v3 of the API.

Though using the v3 API, I saw exactly the same problem when calling this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?orderBy=name&q=name+contains+'search+term'+AND+mimeType+contains+'application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder'&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Strangely, the exact same URL is documented as working when you use the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?orderBy=name&q=name+contains+'search+term'+AND+mimeType+%253D+'application%252Fvnd.google-apps.folder'&_h=2&).

As a last resort, I tried different encoding for the request parameters and the API then worked.

Here's my alternative call which works:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?orderBy=name&q=name%20contains%20%27search%20term%27%20AND%20mimeType%20contains%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This is contrary to the Google Drive documentation, but worked nicely.

Comment: Thanks for this. Have abandoned this for now, but will loop back to this answer when I have some time to picknup the project again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try in the docs tool? https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

The query you are using is correct, just change the version, you are using v2 and I think this param is for v3.

I had some problems too when I was putting the '+' char, I just removed it in the tool and it worked, seems like it was re encoding the char.